# How to save Facebook private message to database?

Tags: php, facebook, api, permissions

My question is that is possible save private message from facebook to my database. And if yes, how is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no permission called "`read_inbox`", and if you mean "`read_mailbox`", you may want to read this:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-read_mailbox

Meaning, you will not get `read_mailbox` approved at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks fo your answer, I mean read_mailbox. My question is that is possible save private message from facebook to my database. And if yes, how is it possible.

Comment: ok, then better create a new question where you ask that question, we require you to write very detailed questions on stackoverflow, it´s not a chat where you just start asking a general question and the real one later ;)

Comment: although, your question can easily be answered: yes, it is possible. see the facebook docs about how exactly. if you get stuck somewhere, create a new question but include what you have tried so far, including example code.